# FacetGrid Seaborn taking long time to plot

Tags: seaborn

I have a major concern regarding why in the world the above code:

> **sns.FacetGrid(iris , row='petal_length' , col='petal_width');**

This statement is taking around 10 minutes to execute and I get a single large extremely large white grid.

Why is this happening please help me removing this behavior of the code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a [minimal complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to your question.

Comment: I guess `petal_length` and `'petal_width'` each contain a lot of dissimilar values. E.g. if each of those columns contained 10 different values, you would already get a grid with 10*10=100 subplots. Drawing that many subplots is expensive and will take a while. Since each of those subplots would then only contain a single point it is also questionable how useful such plot would be. But we don't know what you're aiming at here, so I fear one cannot help further without additional information.

Comment: I want a 2x2 grid where x,y axis are petal_length and petal_width instead of many subplots. I tried without passing row,col args and used .map method to apply scatter plot.In this way it worked fine. I wanted to know why row col was creating so many subplots?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook you need to put "%matplotlib inline" in your code after importing matplotlib.pyplot and seaborn library. It allows jupyter notebook to see the plots and diagram that you are trying to create.

I also got stuck in my NLP project then I remembered I forgot this statement in my code.

Hope it helps.